# Какие приложения/программы есть для проверки запросов REST API?

Tags: java, rest, поиск-программ

Какие приложения/программы есть для проверки запросов REST API? Замечал что те же Post запросы проверяют не через браузер, а через тулзы всякие, подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: В принципе можно Fiddler, но вроде postman как раз для rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postman моя любимая утилита, так же Swagger тоже крутая вещь